# Saving the sqlite databse in android internal memory

Tags: android, sqlite

So I've googled around tried a few examples as well, but so far I haven't been able to find any source that can provide me any knowledge whether I can save my sqlite db in any other folder in the device's internal memory for example in the "/system" folder, I know that its possible to save it in the sd card by simply doing the following

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // All Static variables
    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contactsManager";

    // Contacts table name
    private static final String TABLE_CONTACTS = "contacts";

    // Contacts Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static final String KEY_PH_NO = "phone_number";

    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, "sd card path here "+DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    // Creating Tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_PH_NO + " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
    }
```

But is there any way that i can save the db in the internal memory like in the "/system" folder ?

Comment: You can access the internal memory if you are app is assigned root permissions that is only possible in rooted phones. :)

Comment: @SaqibVohra, my app is a system application so let's say it has the read and write permission, so in that case, can i simply pass the path of the internal memory in the constructor just like the example above or is there a different procedure?

Comment: yup, exactly :) If you have root permissions, you can access the folder simply like /system/app
Here is a similar thread, you will find it useful. :)

Comment: I don't see any link in your comment, if you'd leave this as an answer with that link I'll check that as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have root permissions, you can access the folder simply like /system/app Here is a similar thread, you may find it useful. :)

[how to get access of android root directory (/system/app) programatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16058277/how-to-get-access-of-android-root-directory-system-app-programatically)

P.S: Duplicating comment as i cant paste link their.

Answer (score 2):

> But is there any way that i can save the db in the internal memory like in the "/system" folder ?

No, because you do not have read or write access to that directory.

Comment: For a moment let's assume that I'm developing a system app, that comes bundled with the device, excuse my noobishness but in that case is this possible? and if yes, how do I do that?
P.S. A big fan of you and your book.

Comment: @AalokSharma: A pre-installed app does not necessarily have read or write access to that directory. If it does, then you can read and write to it for a database. And thanks for the kind words!